# How do I detect right clicks with commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

As the title says,  I would like detecting right clicks. 
I have already tried spawning a slime that teleports to the player's head but I don't know how I would build the syntax. How can I do this?

Comment: You could do this one a minecraft server with plugins, but I don't think this is the senioro

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use the scoreboard objectives for stat.useItem. You would have to have a test for command block and objective for every item that the player would use to left click, however.

Comment: Sorry, I meant right click, some dude edited my post do it said left click, but i mean right.

Comment: @Baboom1 Your original post said left clicks, Rudolf L. Jelínek did not change that.